# Clojure: hash-map and array-map type conflicts in defined schema

Tags: java, clojure, hashmap, compojure

I'm working on a Clojure API but ran into this issue regarding Clojure's automatic "type-switching" between `HashMap` and `ArrayMap` when the item count inside the map changes.

Read doc: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/array-map#example-57392e25e4b071da7d6cfd0c

Let's say I have a POST request like this:

```
  (POST "/" []
    :body [foo FooSchema]
    (create-response ok {:message "foo!"}))
```

With `FooSchema` defined like this:

```
(def ArrayMap clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap)

(def Bar ArrayMap)

(s/defschema FooSchema
  {:id    s/Str
   :bar   Bar})
```

`:bar` is sent as a javascript object that has structure like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  fh: 1,
  rdstr: "flying"
}
```

As stated in the documentation, if the `:bar` object returns in the `body` with less than 9 items then it'll yield ArrayMap, which works fine. Anyway, when the `:bar` object scales and return more than 9 items, the request fails, return error:

```
(not (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap a-clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap))
```

because `:bar` was switched to `HashMap` automatically (magically).

Vice versa, if I set the schema type of `:bar` to `HashMap`, then objects with less than 9 items doesn't work neither.

Anyway we can always force the type to `HashMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both types are too specific. You should use a more general type, representing anything map-like. The obvious choice is `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap`.

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. We went with this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [Plumatic Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema).

You can define a predicate for capturing all kind of maps like this

```
(ns your.schema.namespace
  (:require [schema.core :as s]))

(def Map (s/pred map?))

(defschema FooSchema
  {:id s/Str
   :bar Map})
```

`map?` returns `true` for any kind of a map in Clojure

```
=> (map? (array-map))
=> true
=> (map? (hash-map))
=> true
```